# how can i prevent users to share their login details for my web app

Tags: database, security, session, authentication, guard

what i have until now:

1. session on server side
2. unique id (md5) of computer created by **Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT") & REMOTE_HOST** and saved on the database

but what else can i do in this case? users continue to share their login details :(

Comment: Are you trying to stop users giving out their usernames and passwords and letting a lot of people use their accounts?

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem in almost any line of work: from software, where someone can simply copy the program, to simple ticketing, and having an individual walk past the ticketing desk. (I worked in a ticket selling position, and we did have individuals walk in without paying.) This is largely a social problem, not a computing one, and it's  been my experience that trying to fix social problems (people) with computers is largely futile. Here is a culmination of what I've heard on this topic, and the two categories the advice tends to fall into:

**Try to control the problem.**

Try to somehow identify and control the unscrupulous users of the system. This can be DRM for software, or a security guard in the example of the ticketing desk. This is essentially what you're trying now.

A problem I see with your current method is it doesn't support multiple browsers. I routinely browse from multiple browsers, and from multiple websites. If this is your method for identifying theft of your service, are you sure you're not seeing false positives?

If you do try to control the problem, the best thing I've heard is to make sure you don't affect the users legitimately using the system. Causing pain to a legitimate user by either making him install DRM software on his machine, or by requiring him to take off his shoes to get on a plane, only causes him trouble and degrades the apparent quality of your service in his eyes. Try to find ways to identify troublesome users without affecting the normal crowd: selecting blacklisting (banning) of IP addresses might be effective in the case of a web service. (Wikipedia controls spammers and malicious editors this way, and some people have controlled spam email this way.)

Now, the other line of reasoning:

**Ignore the problem.**

This stems from the "don't get in the user's way" ideals. Make your service as good as it can be for the user, and offer him a high quality service that he won't mind parting with his cash. In other words, make it worth his money. This depends on enough people being honest that you're still profitable, of course. Some argue that those who steal a service often wouldn't have paid for it anyways.

In reality, some mix of the two is probably the most effective measure.

Answer (score 2):

Number two doesn't work. I login from at least five different devices. You definitely do not want to couple yourself to the hard- and software upgrade cycle of your customers

Comment: i dont care about, 'cos in instructions of using app the need to use one browser only

Comment: One browser doesn't exist, at least in terms of Request.ServerVariables. A browser autoupdates.

Answer (score 2):

Get an cell phone number of user and send SMS with one-time password each time he tries to login. Email wouldn't work because it is too easy to share.
But you can see a great decrease in your user count: this thing is REALLY annoying.

Comment: And also costly if the userbase is large.

Answer (score 2):

The way I prevent users from sharing account information is by prevent multiple logins from one location. So if the user logs in, it will log out all other sessions.

This is relatively easy to do. Associate to each user in the database a field like session_key that is randomly generated on login. Store that session_key in the database AND in a cookie in the users browser, and check that the session keys match. If not, log the user out. Whenever someone else logs in, it generates a new session key, thus inactivating all previous sessions and logs out the user. You can also try keeping track of other information as well, such as the users IP address, etc associated with the session. It's not 100% foolproof, but it prevents most users from sharing accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Log the IP addresses, times and usernames in a database table. Check the database for users that are active from more than one IP on the site, and ban those users.

Or, stop users from logging into an account if there is a session already on the server for that user.

Comment: this solution good for same access but what if one access in da morning and another one in the evening

Comment: Doesn't work for me, and doesn't work for students. The iPad is on a totally different network. I choose how I work, not you. If you annoy me, I won't use your application

Comment: use the same logic but LIMIT 1 session per a user at a time. So Stephan ye you can login with your ipad but you will get logged out of your desktop machine (which seems like a decent comprise)

Comment: Then I hope you know how to do background saves of data I entered on the page (like Stackoverflow does...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to **prevent** this. You can only make it more difficult - But you should consider the downside: Legitimate users get caught in the crossfire. If I were you, I'd simply tackle the source of the problem - The reason you don't want people to share logins - And fix that instead. Make an incentive *not* to do it. Remove advantages for doing it.

Comment: each login cost money and for my customer it overkill if a lot of people (students) will share their login :(

Answer (score 0):

The only way to stop the users from sharing something is to make that something non-shareable (at least not with some serious hacking). But this involves hardware which can be not appropriate for your project. I am talking about hardware cryptotokens, which hold private keys and don't let one copy them. If you give your user such token with the private key inside, the user can pass the token itself to other person, but he can't copy it.

Answer (score 0):

now i think it is a combination of several factors if not all that can work

1. lower the subscription costs
2. prevent multiple sessions at the same time
3. use two factor auth
4. if app disable screen shots...make too much content on single pages to make it tiresome for someone to scroll down taking screen shots..disable screen recording if possible.....offcose by not giving any permissions
5. i think considering fingerprint scanning and face recognition hand in hand with device ids can work
6. lastly consider loading your website in a webview based app for android users

Answer (score -1):

That's simple. Use the 10 to 15 favourite questions and their answers during registration processes.  Ask randomly one of them during each login.

Comment: Not an ideal solution.